# Top level menu position overwrites another entry

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

From looking at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus#Top-Level_Menus) and after using `print_r($GLOBALS['menu'];` to display the array list of menu items, I see my CPTs listed as

```
16,17,18,19
```

in the returned array. `20` is the `Pages` menu item, and `15` as the `Links` menu item. I have a settings plugin which I wish to display with my Custom Posts. If I add

```
add_menu_page( 'Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'plugin_name', 'plugin_name_options_page', content_url( '/img/icon.png', __FILE__), 20 );
```

Then the `Pages` menu item is overwritten completely by my plugin entry, rather than being moved to `21` etc.

The array for the Posts section in the menu seems to end at 25, so I was thinking I have two options;

1. Figure out how to insert my plugin into the menu array as `20` and move the other pages in the array further along by `1`.
2. Manually set the menu number for my plugin and my CPTs. I have the plugin menu code - how and where do I add similar functionality in my custom posts code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, missed [this codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) page... To solve this the number should be passed as a decimal as a string rather than an int;

```
20 -> '19.1'
```

adjusted code;

```
add_menu_page( 'Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'plugin_name', 'plugin_name_options_page', content_url( '/img/icon.png', __FILE__), '19.1' );
```